# Certain users being denied access to a Windows Server 2008 shared folders in a specific PC

Tags: windows-7, permissions, file-permissions, windows-server-2008-r2

We have a Windows 2008 Server running with shared folders and some users with different permissions.

My problem is that some day, without changing anything in the server, a certain  user started having problems connecting to any of the shared folders, but could use a system that connects to the SQL databe running on it.
I tried logging with my user and everything worked fine.
So I created a new user, granted all the required permissions and so on. All access was granted again as supposed to be.

After a while, the same problem appeared, windows explorer displays an error such as "username not found". But I can access all other computers on the same Domain.

Both users that are now being denied access on that particular machine dont have that problem if I log with them in other machines.

So I figure it has nothing to do with ActiveDirectory in the server, but rather something specific in the machine in the config of those users that somehow change.

Comment: He can log into the same user account on multiple machines connected to the domain?  If that's the case I say its time to restore the troubled machine's image.

Answer (score 0):

This would be due to the replication between your DCs not working.

Here you can see how to check if its replicating: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc794749(v=ws.10).aspx

And here you can find how to trouble shoot it. https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc949120%28v=ws.10%29.aspx

This would happen if the computer is trying to authenticate with the other DC that doesn't have the authentication information of the users.